# How to set variable to for each items

Tags: jsf

I have the below code
`c:set var = "device" value = "{a.sortList}"`

Now i neeed to iterate the loop with device

Like below

```
c: forEach items = "device"
```

this will throw error.

So Please help me , I want to declare the variable globally and use that list inside foreach with that variable , how to achieve. Sorry for any syntax mistakes as I am typing from a mobile

Comment: And where is the code?

Comment: I have the below code
<c:set var = "device" value = "{a.sortList}")>

Now i neeed to iterate the loop with device

Like below
 
<c: forEach items = "device" >  this will throw error.

So Please help me , I want to declare the variable globally and use that list inside foreach with that variable , how to achieve. Sorry for any syntax mistakes as I am typing from a mobile


While clicking edit the question is this dont know Why its not reflecting

Comment: I have removed some symbols now the question is reflecting almost properly

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use:

```
<c:forEach items="${a.sortList}" var="device" varStatus="count">
     ${device}
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<c:set var = "devices" value = "{a.sortList}"/>
<c:forEach items="${devices}" var="device">
    ${device}
</c:forEach>
```